# Can't install pyFFTW with python 3.9 in Macos M1

Tags: python-3.x, conda, pyfftw

Any idea on how can I solve this issue?
I really need to install *pyfftw* into a conda environment, which already has the other libraries I need, such as tensorflow. Up until know, I could only install the other libraries correctly (namely tensorflow) for python 3.9.
I'm working on a Mac M1.
Here is the error output for the command **pip install pyfftw**:

```
    Collecting pyfftw
  Using cached pyFFTW-0.12.0.tar.gz (137 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2.0,>=1.10 in /Users/mymac/miniforge3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pyfftw) (1.19.5)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyfftw
  Building wheel for pyfftw (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/mymac/miniforge3/envs/tf/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/0k/hz9yngm56nz1htdc3c3t3d0c0000gn/T/pip-install-5kpcegg9/pyfftw_56df32e267e3416fb4e9f01e6282e505/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/0k/hz9yngm56nz1htdc3c3t3d0c0000gn/T/pip-install-5kpcegg9/pyfftw_56df32e267e3416fb4e9f01e6282e505/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/0k/hz9yngm56nz1htdc3c3t3d0c0000gn/T/pip-wheel-6urq200p
       cwd: /private/var/folders/0k/hz9yngm56nz1htdc3c3t3d0c0000gn/T/pip-install-5kpcegg9/pyfftw_56df32e267e3416fb4e9f01e6282e505/
  Complete output (25 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9
  creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/pyfftw
  copying pyfftw/config.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/pyfftw
  copying pyfftw/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/pyfftw
  copying pyfftw/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/pyfftw
  creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/pyfftw/builders
  copying pyfftw/builders/builders.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/pyfftw/builders
  copying pyfftw/builders/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/pyfftw/builders
  copying pyfftw/builders/_utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/pyfftw/builders
  creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/pyfftw/interfaces
  copying pyfftw/interfaces/cache.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/pyfftw/interfaces
  copying pyfftw/interfaces/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/pyfftw/interfaces
  copying pyfftw/interfaces/scipy_fft.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/pyfftw/interfaces
  copying pyfftw/interfaces/dask_fft.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/pyfftw/interfaces
  copying pyfftw/interfaces/numpy_fft.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/pyfftw/interfaces
  copying pyfftw/interfaces/scipy_fftpack.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/pyfftw/interfaces
  copying pyfftw/interfaces/_utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/pyfftw/interfaces
  UPDATING build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/pyfftw/_version.py
  set build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/pyfftw/_version.py to '0.12.0'
  running build_ext
  error: Could not find the FFTW header 'fftw3.h'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyfftw
  Running setup.py clean for pyfftw
Failed to build pyfftw
Installing collected packages: pyfftw
    Running setup.py install for pyfftw ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/mymac/miniforge3/envs/tf/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/0k/hz9yngm56nz1htdc3c3t3d0c0000gn/T/pip-install-5kpcegg9/pyfftw_56df32e267e3416fb4e9f01e6282e505/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/0k/hz9yngm56nz1htdc3c3t3d0c0000gn/T/pip-install-5kpcegg9/pyfftw_56df32e267e3416fb4e9f01e6282e505/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/0k/hz9yngm56nz1htdc3c3t3d0c0000gn/T/pip-record-qt54h1vj/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/mymac/miniforge3/envs/tf/include/python3.9/pyfftw
         cwd: /private/var/folders/0k/hz9yngm56nz1htdc3c3t3d0c0000gn/T/pip-install-5kpcegg9/pyfftw_56df32e267e3416fb4e9f01e6282e505/
    Complete output (7 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    UPDATING build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/pyfftw/_version.py
    set build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/pyfftw/_version.py to '0.12.0'
    running build_ext
    error: Could not find the FFTW header 'fftw3.h'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/mymac/miniforge3/envs/tf/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/0k/hz9yngm56nz1htdc3c3t3d0c0000gn/T/pip-install-5kpcegg9/pyfftw_56df32e267e3416fb4e9f01e6282e505/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/0k/hz9yngm56nz1htdc3c3t3d0c0000gn/T/pip-install-5kpcegg9/pyfftw_56df32e267e3416fb4e9f01e6282e505/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/0k/hz9yngm56nz1htdc3c3t3d0c0000gn/T/pip-record-qt54h1vj/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/mymac/miniforge3/envs/tf/include/python3.9/pyfftw Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Forgot to say it. Already edited the question. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PyPA doesn't host a precompiled wheel for **osx-arm64**, so it is building from source. According to [the documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pyFFTW/#description), when source building, one is required to have FFTW installed first. Fortunately, Conda Forge appears to be building this (including **osx-arm64**), so try

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge fftw

pip install pyfftw
```

Otherwise, I dropped [an issue to the Conda Forge feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/pyfftw-feedstock/issues/42), noting that they should be capable of building an **osx-arm64** build. Hopefully that will move forward and in the future one could avoid Pip and local compilation altogether.

**UPDATE**: the feedstock is now building for osx-arm64, so you should be able to use

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge pyfftw
```

Comment: When I run pip install pyfftw (after a successful conda install fftw) I got the same type of errors as above.

Comment: @MrT77 I was worried that might be the case. Likely need to do something to add the Conda environment’s `include/` and `lib/` directories to the compiler/linker search paths. Unfortunately, I can’t troubleshoot it myself at the moment.

Comment: Actually, the feedstock is now building for **osx-arm64**, so you should be able to use `conda install -c conda-forge pyfftw`

Comment: such good news. Thank you, I just installed it.